# Showing Tick/Cross big symbol on correct/incorrect answer

Tags: java, android

I have an android layout with an image view for question figure and two buttons for possible answers, one of them is for correct. I want that if I press correct button a big Tick green symbol should display (but background should be still visible) indicating correct answer, otherwise a red cross big symbol should appear for a file and disappear soon...

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: The way SO works is that you post a code snippet with your doubts/problems, then people can help you.

Comment: In fact I just want to take help how I can draw/put symbol (tick/cross) for a while just to indicate if user selected correct/incorrect option. Could you please just share any helping code to do so?? Thanks!